# Query execution was interrupted, ERROR 1317 (70100)

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

I use mysql command

> mysql -uuser -ppassword -B -e "SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table GROUP BY userId" database > result.tsv &

This is a very slow SQL, I need to use & let SQL execute in the background. which takes about a few hours. But always in the middle of the execution to report a error:

> ERROR 1317 (70100) at line 1: Query execution was interrupted
>   Terminal close -- sending "KILL QUERY 236" to server ...
>   Terminal close -- query aborted.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you executing this on a MySQL server which is not your own computer?  Also, what other things are running in the background which might degrade performance?

Comment: What is the max_allowed_packet size ? You may consider splitting the query as well.

Comment: I am running SQL on MySQL server, and this server only MySQL server installed

Comment: The `max_allowed_packet` value is 16777216, The SQL I want to execute is a SUM operation and returns only one record.